# emacs align-regex fails for wide data

Tags: emacs

I am trying to use C-u M-x align-regex to align these lines

```
a, b, c, d
aa, bb, cc, dd
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   ,            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb        ,         cccccc, ddddddddddddd
    aaa     ,   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     , c, dddd
```

(note: indent-tabs-mode is set to nil (ie use spaces not tabs)

I tried C-u M-x align-regex:

Complex align using regexp: \(,\)[Ret]

Parenthesis group to modify (justify if negative): 1

Amount of spacing (or column if negative): 1

Repeat throughout line? (y or n) y

It resulted in this:

```
a,                    b,                                                              c,              d
aa,                   bb,                                                             cc,             dd
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   ,            bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb        ,                            cccccc, ddddddddddddd
    aaa     ,           bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     , c,              dddd
```

Was expecting the "," to be aligned, and whitespace to be added/removed as necessary

like this:

```
                a,                                                       b,      c,             d
               aa,                                                      bb,     cc,            dd
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,                                bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb, cccccc, ddddddddddddd
              aaa, bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,      c,          dddd
```

Is this some kind of bug or is it that I did not specify the options correctly?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: You probably want the group to be negative, because you want right justification.  See `C-h v align-rules-list`.  But maybe there's a bug too.  I tried to make it work, and could not get it (I fixed some bugs in my own comma aligning function, which uses `align-regexp`).  I've never be able to grok `align-regexp` and friends.